# How to get value of a textbox inside a div using typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have my html like this.

```
<div id="series1">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="Mark">Mark</label>
        <input type="text" id="mark" class="shortTextbox" (blur)="signalSelected('mark')" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to get the value of mark value entered in the text box. This html code repeats for me on a button click. Every time the button is clicked id changes to series2 and series3 and so on.

Currently in typescript file I am taking value like

```
var val = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(selection)).value
```

But this won't give me the value selected for the respective series id. Can you please provide how to get the mark value based on id(series1, series2)...

Comment: You are using Angular2 so why don't you use binding?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `[(ngModel)]="mark"` in your `input field` and a name,
your html component may look like this:

```
<div id="series1">
     <div class="col-md-6">
         <label for="Mark">Mark</label>
          <input type="text" id="mark" class="shortTextbox" [(ngModel)]="mark" (blur)="signalSelected('Mark')" name="mark" />
      </div>
</div>
```

and in your component.ts define a variable and then get it is value like this:

```
...
mark: string;

signalSelected (markVal: string){
    markVal = this.mark
    console.log(markVal); // it is the value
}
```

Comment: If I pass signalSelected('Mark'), Mark is a just a string value which you are assigning in the method

Comment: signalSelected (markVal: string){
    markVal = this.mark

Comment: I tried like (blur)="signalSelected(event) " and in the method I got the value as event.currentTarget.value. This worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngModel`

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myFieldInComponentClass"
```

If you have a field `myFieldInComponentClass` like

```
class MyComponent {
  myFieldInComponentClass:String;
```

this field will have the value assigned whenever the value in the input changes (and also the other way around).

You can make it a getter/setter to execute code on change

```
  private _myFieldInComponentClass:String;
  set myFieldInComponentClass(value :String) {
    this._myFieldInComponentClass = value;
    // other code
  }
  get myFieldInComponentClass() {
    return this._myFieldInComponentClass;
  }
```